# Computer storage issue - Is it okay to delete local files after pushing and deploying on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

Coding newbie here.

This might seem like an odd question, but I am wondering what the usual convention is for developers when they find their computers running out of storage space.

Since I've started pushing more and more local files to GitHub (and deploying them via GitHub Pages), my computer is running out of storage and is found to be slowing down these days. Is it okay for me to delete these local files off my computer? And should I ever need to update / commit new changes and deploy them in the future - can I download them from GitHub and edit the code then and there? (Would I have to re-initialize then?)

Comment: what kind of files do you push to the github? pushing anything to github cannot slow down your computer, or cause shortage of memory. What exactly are you doing?

Comment: There's no reason you can't re-download files stored in Git, though there's also no reason you should be uploading files to Git that are so large that doing so would make a significant difference.

Answer (score 2):

Once your files are checked into source control, provided you have added everything that isn't a temporary or build file it should be safe to delete the code.

> Since I've started pushing more and more local files to GitHub (and deploying them via GitHub Pages), my computer is running out of storage and is found to be slowing down these days.

I find it strange that the amount of files you are working with would clutter up your whole computer unless you are dealing with binaries or lots of images or something.

A better thing to do is to use `find` (assuming you're on linux / osx) to find all of your computers large files and do an audit of them:

### Find all files over 100mbs

```
find . -type f -size +100M
```

### Find all files over 1000mbs

```
find . -type f -size +1000M
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have atleast 2 branches in git hub which has complete data.

When you delete files from your branch when try to commit then those files will be in untracked. If by mistake you run `git commit - am` When you commit then those files will be deleted from main branch too.

Everytime you need to pull code from github from main branch create new branch commit, push, merge to new branch and then delete files. It depends on how often you delete them. Infact once you pull the data then you will face same issue.

Rather creating one repo, create multiple repo so that later on you can intergrate your code. In that way you can delete as i suggested above.

Comment: This sounds like a rather complicated and error-prone workflow.